# Why this algorithm to determine is divisible or not work?

Tags: c, math

```cpp
static inline bool is_divisible(uint32_t n, uint64_t M) {
    return n * M <= M - 1;
}

static uint64_t M3 = UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) / 3 + 1;
....
uint8_t div3 = is_divisible(17, M3);
```

As mention in title, this function can determine whether `n` is divisible by 3.
The only thing I figure out is that `M` is same as `ceil((1<<64)/d)` which `d` is 3.

Are there anyone call explain why `is_divisible` work? thanks!

Comment: This appears to be relying on integer overflow.  I don't see how this is better than using a simple modulo operator.

Comment: @paddy divide operation is expensive for processor. multiply is cheaper. also `M3` can be derermine before run time.

Comment: It depends on the processor.  Are you targeting a specific one?  Is this "divisible" operation a known bottleneck for your program?  Performing a 64-bit multiplication may also have drawbacks.  Especially on processors that do not have native 64-bit support.  Also, operating on 64-bit values halves the possible number of concurrent operations, which affects potential performance gains that could be made through vectorized instructions if available on your platform.

Comment: @Steven Yes, but if you change the function to `return n % 3 == 0;`, the optimizer will convert the division to a multiplication anyways, so there's no need for this code.

Comment: Hint: work out what `2*M3` and `3*M3` are.  Then write your number as `n=3*x+y` where `y` is either `0`, `1` or `2`.  Using properties of arithmetic, determine what `n*M3` could be, and when it is less than `M3-1`.

Comment: Indeed using these kinds of optimizations usually [*hinders* the *good* compilers from generating effective code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455800/malloc-in-c-same-sizeof-before-and-after). Just use `M3 % 17` and let the compiler figure it ou

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Or do you want `n%3` in this case? "determine whether n is divisible by 3"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not clang or Godbolt, I couldn't figure out what that code does :P

Comment: the snippet above can be found in [Faster remainders when the divisor is a constant: beating compilers and libdivide](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/02/08/faster-remainders-when-the-divisor-is-a-constant-beating-compilers-and-libdivide/). Explanation: [Efficient divisibility testing](https://web.archive.org/web/20180817163253/http://clomont.com/efficient-divisibility-testing/)

Comment: Some examples: [Divisiblity of 5 without using % and / operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121753/995714), [Fast divisibility tests (by 2,3,4,5,.., 16)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49264279/995714), [How to check if given number is divisible of 15 in fastest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706614/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Divide *n* by 3 to find quotient *q* and remainder *r*, allowing us represent *n* as *n* = 3*q* + *r*, where 0 ≤ r < 3.

Intuitively, multiple 3*q* + *r* by (2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1 causes the *q* portion to vanish because it wraps modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, leaving the remainder portion to be in one of three segments of [0, 2<sup>64</sup>) depending on the value of *r*. The comparison with *M3* determines whether it is in the first segment, meaning *r* is zero. A proof follows.

Note that *M3* is (2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1.

Then *n*•*M3* = (3*q* + *r*)•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) = *q*•(2<sup>64</sup>−1)+3*q*+*r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) = *q*•2<sup>64</sup>+2*q*+*r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1).

When this is evaluated with `uint64_t` arithmetic, the *q*•2<sup>64</sup> term vanishes due to wrapping modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, so the computed result is
2*q*+*r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1).

Suppose *n* is a multiple of 3. Then *r* = 0. Since *n* is a `uint32_t` value, *q* < 2<sup>32</sup>, so 2*q*+*r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) = 2*q* < 2<sup>33</sup> < *M3*.

Suppose *n* is not a multiple of 3. Then *r* = 1 or *r* = 2. If *r* = 1, *r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) = (2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1 > *M3*−1. And, of course, if *r* = 2, *r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) is even greater and also exceeds *M3*−1. However, we need to be concerned about wrapping in `uint64_t` arithmetic. Again, since *q* < 2<sup>32</sup>, we have, for *r* = 2, 2*q*+*r*•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) < 2•2<sup>32</sup> + 2•((2<sup>64</sup>−1)/3 + 1) = 2<sup>33</sup> + 2/3•2<sup>64</sup> − 2/3 + 2 = 2<sup>64</sup> − 1/3•2<sup>64</sup> + 2<sup>33</sup> + 4/3, which is clearly less than 2<sup>64</sup>, so no wrapping occurs.