# is sizeof a pointer equal to sizeof a pointer to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

when I got an array of pointers and a pointer why sizeof the array of poninters is equal to the sizeof pointer?
for example:

```
char *matrixp;
char **m;
printf("%llu", sizeof matrixp);
printf("%llu", sizeof m);
```

gives back the same output.
is there a way I can get the total size in bytes for example of

```
char *vet[10]
```

? (that should be 80).

Comment: Use `%zu` format specifier for `size_t`

Comment: All pointers are the same size.

Comment: An array looks like `char array[5]`, and you don't have any of those. Try adding one and see what sizeof gives you then.

Comment: Use `sizeof vet` to get the size of that array.

Comment: @Barmar but an array of pointers, for example char *vet[10], does not have inside of it 10 pointers? so 80 bytes?? for 64arch

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, it does. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @tstanisl: Or else cast the result to an integer type large enough to hold the numerical value and use a format specifier appropriate for that type.  Especially in the embedded world, support for `%zu` is not universal, since supporting for it would represent a gratuitous waste of code space when processing programs that don't require it.

Comment: @Barmar because the output of the sizeofs is the same as if it was with just 1 pointer

Comment: sizeof m is 8, sizeof vet is 80

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to print on the screen the total number of pointer inside the array??

Comment: @stark can you share your code?

Comment: It is right above these comments

Comment: m is a pointer, so has size 8. vet is an array of 10 pointers so has size 80. sizeof does not care what a pointer points to.

Comment: @Sebastian `sizeof vet / sizeof vet[0]` is `10`, the number of pointers in the array.

Comment: @Sebastian [try it and see](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rnqhTavE3)

Comment: I think this question is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455800/malloc-in-c-same-sizeof-before-and-after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All pointer have the same size (8 bytes). If you want to get the total size of an array (like `char *vet[10]`), you have to declare it as an array (with `[]`) and not as a pointer (`char **vert`). `*vert[10]` is an array of 10 pointers while `**vert` is a pointer to the start of an area of memory containing pointers.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *chars[] = {"hello", "world", "pointers"}; // declared as an array of strings/pointers
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(chars[0])); // pointer to the start of 'hello' (size is 8)
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(chars[1])); //pointer to start of 'world' (still 8 bytes)
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(chars)); // refers to the whole array (24 bytes)

    char **m; // a pointer pointing to the first pointer in m (not an array)
    char *n; // another pointer pointing to the first letter in n
    n = "pointer";
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(n)); // 8
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(m)); // 8

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For all practical purposes, you're right.  But it's not *REQUIRED* by the standard.  See John Bode's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228911/421195).  And thank you for pointing out (pun intended) the importance of "%zu" (vs. "%llu").

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title - pointers to different types (including pointer types) do *not* all have to be the same size.  The only requirements are:

- `char *` and `void *` have the same size and alignment;
- Pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as pointers to their unqualified equivalents (e.g., `sizeof (int *) == sizeof (const int *)`;
- All `struct` pointer types have the same size and alignment;
- All `union` pointer types have the same size and alignment;

So it's not *guaranteed* that an `int *` is the same size as an `int **` or
an `int (*)[N]`, but for commodity hardware like x86_64 it tends to be true.

Now, for your specific questions:

First of all, a `sizeof` expression has type `size_t`, for which we need to use the `%zu` conversion specifier in `printf`. Using `%llu` on a `size_t` argument is technically undefined behavior.  Rewrite those statements as

```
printf("%zu", sizeof matrixp);   
printf("%zu", sizeof m);
```

and see if you still get the same output.  You *shouldn't* because you've defined `matrixp` as a plain `char` (at least in the code you've posted here), and `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition, and I will guarantee no pointer type is only one byte wide (unless you're working on a system that only has 256 addressable memory locations).

**Edit**

And now someone has changed the types from `char` and `char *` to `char *` and `char **`, so that paragraph is now wrong.  Awesome.

For x86 and x86_64 platforms, all pointer types do have the same size and representation, so if you're running this on Windows or Linux you should get the same output.  Just be aware that's not universally true.

**End edit**

Secondly, `sizeof` evaluates to the number of bytes in the operand (whether the operand is a type name or expression).  `sizeof vet` will yield the total number of bytes used by the `vet` array (`10 * sizeof (char *)`).  To get the number of *elements* (`10`), you'll have to divide the result of `sizeof vet` by the size of an individual element, `sizeof vet[0]` (or `sizeof *vet`, which evaluates to the same thing).